# Creating multiple Webpack builds and handling optional dependecies

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash

I'm using webpack to create a few different builds of a library I'm creating:

- Kitchen sink build - includes all the global deps built into it already, can be used as a simple script include on the page.
- Module build - Only includes the library code, no deps are included. The implementer must make sure the deps are available themselves.

I have 2 webpack configs, one for each build. The main difference between the webpack config files is the minimal build uses the `externals` configurations like below, which omits the deps from the build.

```
{
  lodash: {
    commonjs: 'lodash',
    commonjs2: 'lodash',
    amd: 'lodash',
    root: '_'
  },
  rsvp: {
    commonjs: 'rsvp',
    commonjs2: 'rsvp',
    amd: 'rsvp',
    root: 'RSVP'
  }
}
```

This works great if I want to include ALL of lodash in my kitchen sink build. But considering lodash is somewhat large and I'm only using ~ 3 functions from lodash I'd like to move over to a custom build that includes only the functions I'm using to minimize file size. I successfully created the custom build of lodash and it works as expected with my kitchen sink build.

The issue I'm encountering is the minimal build now includes the custom lodash build instead of looking for a global instance.

I think the issue stems from mapping the `externals` to the lodash import I changed to when using a local build of lodash.

```
// My original import that correctly removed lodash from minimal build
var _ = require('lodash')

// The new import I'm using to use my custom build
var _ = require('./utilities/lodash.custom')
```

For context here is the build command I'm using to create my lodash:

```
node ./node_modules/lodash-cli/bin/lodash -p include=partial,merge,find exports=node -o utilities/lodash.custom.js
```

Anyone have any idea how to use externals correctly for a custom lodash build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after messing around with different configuration options in webpack a bit more. I'm answering my own question in the event someone else stumbles on this with the same issue.

I was able to update the webpack configuration to create an alias to `lodash` to my custom lodash build, so when I import lodash, it actually imports my local build instead of what was downloaded from NPM.

My index.js file import for lodash remains the same, as if I'm importing from NPM:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

I then create a custom build of lodash that includes only the required functions for my code. This will generate a static build under `./utilites/lodash.custom.js` file.

```
node ./node_modules/lodash-cli/bin/lodash -p include=partial,merge,find exports=node -o utilities/lodash.custom.js
```

Then in my `webpack.conf.js` file I added a `resolve` section that points the `lodash` namespace to my local lodash build.

**kitchen-sink-build.webpack.config.js**

```
{
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    library: 'CorsClient',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: 'CorsClient.js'
  },
  target: 'web',
  plugins: [],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'lodash': './utilities/lodash.custom'
    }
  }
}
```

This will generate an output file that uses my custom lodash build and includes it as a dependency. This kitchen sink build will be able to be used as a standalone script on any website.

By adding another block to the `webpack.conf.js` file I can then tell webpack to NOT include lodash but to expect it to be available in the global scope already:

**module-build.webpack.config.js:**

```
{
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    library: 'CorsClient',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: 'CorsClient.js'
  },
  target: 'web',
  plugins: [],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'lodash': './utilities/lodash.custom'
    }
  },
  externals: {
    lodash: {
      commonjs: 'lodash',
      commonjs2: 'lodash',
      amd: 'lodash',
      root: '_'
    }
  }
}
```

This build will omit lodash as a dependency and rely on the implementer to import lodash manually. This makes it perfect for importing as a dependency into another project that already has full lodash or a custom lodash build that includes at minimum the same lodash functions.